# Numerical functions as constraints for NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to use `NMaximize` to solve a problem like this:

$\quad \quad  \max_y f(y) \text{ subject to } \max_x g(x, y) \leq c.$

Rather than reproduce my (messier) problem, I have provided a very simple example of how I tried to solve this problem:

```
f[y_] := 1 - y
g[x_, y_] := x - y
NMaximize[{f[y], y >= 0, NMaximize[{g[x, y], 0 <= x <= 1}, x][1] <= 1/2}, y]
```

This shows my problem, which is that `NMaximize` does not nest in this way: It seems that rather than plug the same `y` in for both problems, *Mathematica* attempts to evaluate the inner function first and then complains that `y` is not a number:

> NMaximize::nnum: The function value -0.0914636+y is not a number at {x} = {0.0914636}. >>

Is there an alternative approach that could solve a problem like this one?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this?

```
Clear[f, g, maxg];
f[y_] := 1 - y
g[x_, y_] := x - y
maxg[y_?NumericQ] := NMaxValue[{g[x, y], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
NMaximize[{f[y], y >= 0 && maxg[y] <= 1/2}, y]

(*  {0.500001, {y -> 0.499999}}  *)
```

See this answer for more information about the use of [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html):
[What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

There is some subtlety here that I think makes this question not a duplicate of it or its linked questions.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Now I'll read up on this so that I understand why!